# Pyinstaller app(console) won't work

Tags: python, macos, pyinstaller

I've trouble making an CONSOLE app work after packaging. 
App flashes once and closes. 
in terminal i've put: `pyinstaller --onefile --windowed --icon=name.icns Script.py`

So far i've tried running the app through terminal to try and get error ( you know like in windows but it failed lol ).

Is there a way to see the reason why it closed?

EDIT:
When i run Executable within app i get this error:

```
File "Script.py", line 14, in <module>


File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 389, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)

File "site-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 43, in <module>

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 389, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)

File "site-packages/urllib3/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 389, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)

File "site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 28, in <module>

File "site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 92, in __get__

File "site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 115, in _resolve

File "site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 82, in _import_module
ImportError: No module named 'queue'
```

I have nothing about "queue" in code and .py works great and gives no import error.

Thank you.

Comment: Without some required interaction, the console will close when the application finishes execution. You can add something at the end of your script `input("Press <Enter> to exit. ")` to hold the console open.

Comment: I have multiple inputs, it is automation tool for something and requires user input.

Comment: if the app is closing then it's encountering an exception that you're not catching. You could try to put your entire function in a try/except statement and use something like `traceback.print_exc()` to print the error, followed by an `input` statement to hold the console open.

Comment: Flashes twice in dock and closes, window doesn't open at all and no error given.

Comment: I've added some info in question, might help. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Seems like there's an error importing one of your modules, perhaps its dependencies aren't being detected correctly.

You can try to explicitly add a module via the command line by including `--hidden-import=queue`, you might have to do this for more modules that haven't been detected. More discussion in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22104506/pyinstaller-failing-to-include-some-modules-from-c-python27-lib).

Comment: Thank you, will give it a try and if it works i will upvote the comment